# PHP mPDF problemas com código de barras

Tags: php, mpdf

Eu recebo uma URL de um boleto gerado em ASP, uso a classe mPDF para enviar esse boleto pro servidor, recupero o boleto gerado e envio por e-mail com PHPMailer. O que acontece é que no gmail o código de barras do boleto está diferente de quando eu acesso diretamente pela URL

**SEGUE UM EXEMPLO DO CÓDIGO DE BARRAS DO BOLETO EM ASP**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CÓDIGO DE BARRAS DO BOLETO GERADO COM mPDF**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esses são os mesmos boletos, porém com código de barras diferente. Segue um exemplo do código onde eu gero o boleto com mPDF:

```
$location = '/usr/local/se/web/wwwroot/temp/';

$url = file_get_contents($path);

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4', [197, 296]]);
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->writeHTML($url);

ob_clean();

$pathArchive = $location . createRandomOID() . '.pdf';

$mpdf->Output($pathArchive);

return $pathArchive;
```

alguma dica de como posso resolver? Já li a documentação do mPDF e nada resolveu.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVIDO**

eu resolvi com a função str_replace do PHP, alterei a largura dos pixels do código de barras, dessa forma:

$url = file_get_contents($path);

```
//troca os pixels de largura do código de barras do boleto
$new_url = str_replace(array('img src=http://boletos.schulze.com.br/p.gif width=1 height=50 border=0','img src=http://boletos.schulze.com.br/b.gif width=1 height=50 border=0'), array('img src=http://boletos.schulze.com.br/p.gif width=1.5 height=50 border=0','img src=http://boletos.schulze.com.br/b.gif width=1.5 height=50 border=0'), $url);
```

e assim o arquivo PDF foi anexado com todas as barras no email.